# combination of eval + f-strings + match-case

Tags: python, pattern-matching, eval, f-string

How do I make the following work,

```
for i in ['int', 'bool']:
  x = eval(f'match 1: \
               case {i}(): print(1)')
```

that is I want to run a match-case f-string inside an eval.

Comment: Don't you need a parameter to the call to `int/bool`?

Comment: I am inspecting the match-case on the builtins. I was able to solve this problem, by using, `cc = compile(f'match 1:\n\tcase {i}(): print(1)','<string>','single')
  y = eval(cc)`

Comment: Parameter is optional

Comment: But surely in that case they can't return `1`? `int()` will return `0` and `bool()` will return `False`

Comment: case is like a type check, it does not evaluate, so, `int()` would just check whether `1` is an integer (and print `1`), and `bool()` will just check whether `1` is a bool (and print nothing). it does not evaluate `int()` to `0` or `bool()` to `False`

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot about matching against classes... juggling too many languages in my head...

Answer (score 1):

`eval`  only evaluates Python expressions. `match` is a [*statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching). So you should use `exec`:

```
for i in ['int', 'bool']:
  exec(f'match 1:\n \
  case {i}(): print(1)')
```

(also beware of line breaks/indents inside f-strings)